# Best way to offering multiple subscriptions for one user (iOS, Android)

Tags: in-app-purchase, app-store, google-play-services, subscription

Does anyone have experience implementing multiple subscriptions model for an app? I wasn't able to find proper documentation about this topic. The most common way to create in-app subscription model is one-subscription per one-user. But I want to offer one-subscription per one-item(in my app). This means that users can create multiple subscriptions if they want to subscribe to multiple items. Each item is functionally the same.

For example, If the app is a pet location tracker and wants to track both pet A and B, the user has to subscribe to each A and B respectively. It means a total of 2 subscriptions.

Please explain it to me.
Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Never thought about such a use case, but for iOS you can create multiple subscriptions. So you could create a subscription PetA, PetB, PetC and so on. But, I think you asked for a more dynamic approach where you create a Pet subscription and the user can buy as much as he likes. As far as I know this isn't possible.

A different approach would be to create a subscription hierarchy: onePet, twoPets, threePets and so one. Your user can then up or down grade between those subs depending on how many pets he wants to track. Could get messy if you also want to offer different durations.

A third approach could be to use consumable IAPs. These can be purchased as often as the user likes, but have the disadvantage that you need to keep track of the validity period on your own and they can't be synced automatically between multiple devices.

For your pet example I would go for the second approach and offer a onePet, twoPet, threePet and a unlimitPet subscription. This is the most maintainable approach as long as you do not offer endless duration variations. Also this gets synced automatically with all devices of the user and if you like you can also support family sharing.