# Multi Subscriptions for same plan

Tags: react-native, in-app-purchase, applepay

I'm building react-native app.

Subscription Plan A: 1$

Subscription Plan B: 2$

I need to implement purchase multiple same plans like below

PlanA * n + PlanB * k

But InAppPurchase doesn't allows purchasing multi subscriptions for same plan.

Otherwise, If I use Stripe then Apple will reject my app.

Is there any brilliant way?

Comment: May I use apple pay?

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the meaning of `user buys PlanA n times` you could use non-renewing subscriptions. You lose automatic renewal, but users can buy a subscription multiple times (each purchase increases the eligibility duration to the corresponding content of PlanA).

Based on the provided information, I don't see any other solution.

Comment: thanks for your answer. But I don't want increasing duration but buy same subscription plans  at the same time.

Comment: What is the effect of buying the same subscription?

Comment: Do you plan to do something similar to this question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/65912876/1128713

Comment: It's not related to effect. it's requirement.